# PHP Explode new line into an array for json

Tags: php, string, escaping, interpolation

I have data in my database(mysql) that I am trying to pull to a page in json format so I can pick at the data for future reference.

Current data output

```
{
    "quotes": [
        {
            "season": "3",
            "episode": "2",
            "lines": [
                "Boys:\tSchool day, school day, teacher's golden ru\nKyle:\tAh, damn it! My little brother's trying to follow me to school, again. "
            ]
        },
        {
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "2",
            "lines": [
                "Episode 2 "
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is getting `lines` to display like so

```
"lines": [
           {"Boys": "School day, school day, teacher's golden ru"},
           {"Kyle": "Ah, damn it! My little brother's trying to follow me to school, again."}
         ]
```

**The PHP I have**

```
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM quotes");
$response = array();
$i=0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $response[$i]['season']= $row['season'];
    $response[$i]['episode']= $row['episode'];
    $response[$i]['lines'] = explode('\n', $row['lines']);
    $data['quotes'][$i] = $response[$i];
    $i=$i+1;
}
$json_string = json_encode($data);

echo $json_string;
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: The problem with key `lines` is that there is no key that differs each line said, e.g `Boys` or `Kyle`. I guess it's because `Kyle` might say 2 lines, this will overwrite each line by his last said line. Is there a rule in the structure of the lines, e.g. that `\n` is always the end of each and `\t` is the start of a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$response[$i]['lines'] = explode('\n', $row['lines']);
```

With

```
$lines = explode("\n", $row['lines']);
$indexedLines = array();

foreach( $lines as $thisLine ) {
    $sepIndex    = strpos( $thisLine, ":\t" );
    $lineIndex   = substr( $thisLine, 0, $sepIndex );
    $lineContent = substr( $thisLine, $sepIndex + 2 );
    $indexedLines[ $lineIndex ] = $lineContent;
}
$response[$i]['lines'] = $indexedLines;
```

For a model that allows for multiple lines per speaker, and preserves the order of the lines, replace:

```
$indexedLines[ $lineIndex ] = $lineContent;
```

With something along the lines of:

```
$indexedLines[] = array( 'speaker' => $lineIndex, 'line' => $lineContent );
```

Comment: This code seems to do what I want but a very large amount of the output it missing. Trying to figure out how as well as there is quotes in the output

Comment: If you can provide more of the data then I'm sure it can be solved, but the answer posted will output exactly what you want for the examples you give...

Comment: The most obvious issue is that the data-format you suggest only allows for one quote per person.  E.g. the second quote by "Boys" will overwrite the first one.

Comment: In which case, what you're asking for simply isn't possible.  The data format you've stated doesn't allow it.  Maybe a slightly different format will give you what you're looking for instead.

Comment: I.E. the description you've given for the lines array is:  I want an array where the index of each element is the name of person speaking, the content is the line spoken.  This only allows for one line per person.

Comment: E.g.  Change the line $indexedLines[ $lineIndex ] = $lineContent; to $indexedLines[] = array( 'Speaker' => $lineIndex, 'Line' => $lineContent );

Answer (score 6):

```
explode('\n', $row['lines']);
```

should be

```
explode("\n", $row['lines']);
```

Note the double quote. Control characters expressed with preceding back slash must be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks this works and shows as `"Boys:\tSchool day, school day, teacher's golden ru",` but is there a way to get it like `{"Boys": "School day, school day, teacher's golden ru"},`

Comment: If you mean to remove the tabs (\t) just do explode("\n", str_replace("\t", "", $row['lines']))

Answer (score -2):

```
$line = array();
$lines = array();

$line['Boys'] = "School day, school day, teacher's golden ru";
$line['Kyle'] = "Ah, damn it! My little brother's trying to follow me to school, again.";

$lines['lines'] = $line;
```

good luck!

Comment: Could you explain what in the code you have posted is an answer to the problem happening here, so that the user and future readers can learn from it?