# PHP json_decode adding extra quote marks to string

Tags: php, json, laravel, php-8

I'm trying to json_decode a JSON package from the database and then explode one of the properties by '\n' as follows. I'm in laravel so I've dd'd all the variables as they go through the process

```
 $options = json_decode($field['options'],true);
 $rows = explode('\n', $options['choices']);
 dd($field['options'],$options,$rows,'here');
```

See the screenshot of the printed results. $field['options'] looks like a good JSON string.

When decoded, $options has extra quote marks added.

Exploding the weird string doesn't work.

[image: See the screenshot here]

Tried to JSON decode an object and returned extra quote marks in the string, now I can't explode the string.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: add the value of `$field` to your question so that we help you debug.

Comment: "the 3 quotes are something that the vardumper components wraps the string around to indicate that it's a multiline string. It's not actually in your variable." from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609373/object-return-three-open-close-quote-in-php-laravel) by @apokryfos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Explode new line into an array for json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933633/php-explode-new-line-into-an-array-for-json#19933703)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is using the single quote for the `\n`, it will *NOT* interpret to `newline`, you need using double quote.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

No problems with my code to extract the multiline data

```
$dataJson = '{"choices": "council| Council tax\nelectric|Electricity\nwifi/WiFi\nwater|Water\ngas|Gas"}';
$dataArray = json_decode($dataJson, true);
var_export( explode("\n", $dataArray['choices']) );
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'council| Council tax',
  1 => 'electric|Electricity',
  2 => 'wifi/WiFi',
  3 => 'water|Water',
  4 => 'gas|Gas',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so the extra quote marks were a bit of a curve-ball...

There was nothing wrong with the json_decode as @pickuse mentioned.

The issue was with the explode. Instead of using '\n' as the delimiter, you should use PHP_EOL as follows:

```
$rows = explode('\n', $options['choices']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help, but there would be a problem that I just noticed after submitting this the first time.
Mine reads a file so I needed to trim all the returns, trim($line) and also I stripped out all \n, str_replace("\n",'',$line).

This will likely to cause a problem with array:2[choices => and Array:1 [0 =>  as the \n is the delimiter. So you're going to need to encapsulate those values.

This is what I wrote a while back to turn json into yaml.  I trim each line, contact the string then strip all new lines "\n" and then decode the long json string.

```
<?
$file='rewbin-test.json';
$handle = fopen($file,'r');
$data='';   ###>  This is going to be a long string no line breaks. 
            ###> I think it should be your $field['options'] value.
$dec= array ();  ###>  This array I create
//$records=array();
while($line = fgets($handle)){
    $data.=trim($line); ###> This representing your $field['options'] value.
}
fclose($handle);
            //echo $data;
$data=str_replace("\n",'',$data);
            echo $data; ###>  long string no-returns and no "\n"

$dec=json_decode($data, true);
            print_r($dec);
    ###> this is multi-dimension array I think you're looking for.

/*
$yaml=var_dump(yaml_emit($dec));  ###> convert array to yaml.
print $yaml;            
*/
?>
```

10 lines from the rewbin-test.json file. In the file there are returns.

```
{
  "canIpForward": false,
  "confidentialInstanceConfig": {
    "enableConfidentialCompute": false
  },
  "deletionProtection": false,
  "description": "",
  "disks": [
    {
      "autoDelete": true,
```

In the $data var there are no returns.

That portion in the array.

```
Array
(
    [canIpForward] =>
    [confidentialInstanceConfig] => Array
        (
            [enableConfidentialCompute] =>
        )

    [deletionProtection] =>
    [description] =>
    [disks] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [autoDelete] => 1
                    [boot] => 1
```

Hope this is helpful.
rew